# Android Garbage collector

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection

Example I have create new object on **onCreate Event** in activity like :

```
Object object = new Object();
```

I have asssigned **objct** to null, in order to prevent leak memory.

Is it good way to set it null in **onDestroy event**?

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    object = null;
}
```

Comment: NO NEED, art runtime will take care of GC .  you should care about memory leak . not the GC.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: while there are certain tasks that should be done (like unregisterring BroadcastReceivers, stopping background tasks, etc.) in `onDestroy`, nullifying the variables is not one of them. You don't need to nullify anything ever except you strictly need it for your code to work.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a question of "is it good", it's a question of is it worth the time writing it? Well, no.

It's because of Android way of writing code. In android, `Activity` must not be referenced outside its own or its subcomponents. This way, when the `onDestroy()` is called, Android can let go of the last reference to Activity allowing the GC to collect it and all of its objects, including your `object`.

What you should put your time on is to figure out how to stop all the background threads that you started in the `Activity` and stop them at `onDestroy()`.

Comment: I meant if he starts his own thread, like he creates his object in the `Activity`. Then he should clean it up at `onDestroy()`.